# How should I choose between a CustomOperator and a PythonOperator?

Tags: airflow

When I write a custom operator, it executes some arbitrary Python code in its `execute` method:

```
class FooOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, some_arg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        self.some_arg = arg
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        return self.some_arg
```

I could also use a `PythonOperator` which calls an executable which does the same as this `execute` method does:

```
def foo(some_arg: str):
  return some_arg

...

PythonOperator(task_id="foo", python_callable=foo,  op_args={"some_arg": "bar})
```

What is the difference between using a custom operator vs a `PythonOperator` and what can help me decide which I should use?